# HTML Elements inside an image?

Tags: html, css, authentication, interface

i made a container for my login page that is composed of 3 images

```
    frost_frame_top.png
    frost_frame_body.png
    frost_frame_bottom.png
```

and it appears like this

[image]

i done it by doing this in its .css

```
    #loginframe_top, #loginframe_center, #loginframe_bottom
    {
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

i like to add some elements like textbox, buttons and labels inside the image. how can i do this ? i am new to web development and hope i can find some answers. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest other elements inside an `<image>` tag. Even if it somehow works in one browser, it will likely fail in other browsers because it's a self-closing tag.

Instead, use the correct elements for your purpose:
[textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp), [Button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) and [Label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp). It sounds like you need to nest them all inside a form to make it work in a simple way (if you are not going to useg javascript for validation, for example).

Answer (score 0):

create a div"container" in which you want to add textbox, buttons and labels and give position absolute to it

```
.container{position absolute; top:0px;}
```

and put both images div and container div in a parent div and give it position:relative

Comment: i don't know how to do it properly, but this is how i 
[did it](http://pastebin.com/LuvuWCLj) and appeared 
[like this](http://i.imgur.com/K9YORKZ.png)

the only problem is it keeps being left align .. i want it to be centered

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a div with the image as a background and inside the div you use the elements.

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" />     
</div>

.container {
height:346px;
width:678px;
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsWHu.png) no-repeat;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/0jvhzo6g/

Answer (score 0):

If u need contain your html-element(s) inside of image u can do like this:

```
            <div>
                <img src={item.photo}
                     alt={item.name}
                     width={"100%"}
                />
                <div style={{ left: "80%", bottom: "80%", position: "relative", zIndex: 100}}>
                    Text or icon
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but adding an explanation alongside the code could be useful.

Comment: There are containing several objects in "div", one of them - your image, onether - your overlap-content. Your overlap-content has position "relative" and u can set coordinates for him by left/right/top/bottom/inset styles. BTW - style z-index isn`t necessary.